# Poor Transparency on Images

Tags: android

I am having problems getting transparency to work well on an ImageView. The images at (http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/6233/whatn.png) were screen captured from a Droid (hdpi). The top image I made in Photoshop and left the background white. The bottom image is the same image with the background transparent and the layout's color (white) shows through.

Whenever I have transparent backgrounds in images it dithers shadows like this. Also, it only happens on hdpi devices, on my G1 (mdpi) it looks just fine. What is going on? How can I make the bottom image look as good as the top one?

Comment: I don't see any difference in those pictures, how are you comparing them?

Comment: It might be hard to see on a computer monitor but the issue is very apparent on my Droid with its high pixel density. The text shadow does not smoothly transition. This issue seemed to show up as a "feature" in Android 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the window `PixelFormat` in your Activity

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

Answer (score 0):

In older device and simulator, you should use png image with transparent channel. Try re-open your image and save as with a transparent channel.

Comment: Forgot to say that the original images are png-24 with transparency enabled